# Different image in each cell of a UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I want to set a different image for each cell of my table view. I don't know how to do this -- please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom cell with a UIImageView in it, but the simplest way is to set the built in image view of the default UITableViewCell in your -cellForRowAtIndexPath table view delegate. Something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //... other cell initializations here
}

[[cell imageView] setImage:image];
```

Where image is a UIImage that you created by loading from a URL or from the local application bundle.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create a property to store an array of different image names.

   In your header (`.h`) file:

   ```
   @interface MyViewController : UITableViewController {
       NSArray *cellIconNames;
       // Other instance variables...
   }
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *cellIconNames;
   // Other properties & method declarations...
   @end
   ```

   In your implementation (`.m`) file:

   ```
   @implementation MyViewController
   @synthesize cellIconNames;
   // Other implementation code...
   @end
   ```
2. In your `viewDidLoad` method, set the `cellIconNames` property to an array containing the different image names (in the order they want to appear):

   ```
   [self setCellIconNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lake.png", @"Tree.png", @"Water.png", @"Sky.png", @"Cat.png", nil]];
   ```
3. In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` table view data source method, get the image name that corresponds with the cell's row:

   ```
   NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIconNames] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   ```

   Then create a `UIImage` object (using `cellIconName` to specify the image) and set the cell's `imageView` to this `UIImage` object:

   ```
   UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];
   [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];
   ```

After step 3, your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method would look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /* Initialise the cell */

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    /* Configure the cell */

    NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIconNames] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

    // Other cell configuration code...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is listIcon in this code , and where we are using the cellIconNames that we are using as an array.

Comment: @uttam: Whoops! `listIcon` should be `cellIcon` (I've corrected the code now). `cellIconNames` is an `NSArray`, so we use it as an array...

Comment: what is step 4 , you have given the step-1,2,3 but not the step-4,.
and is setCellIconNames is same as cellIconNames.

Comment: @uttam: I originally had split step 3 into two steps (3 & 4), but forgot to change "After steps 3 & 4" to "After step 3". Sorry! As for `setCellIconNames`, see http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1. Basically, `setCellIconNames` is a method (which is automatically generated because we have declared the `cellIconNames` property) that changes the value of the `cellIconNames` instance variable. This type of method is called a mutator/setter.

Comment: @uttam: I would strongly recommend you read http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/, which gives you a very good introduction to Objective-C/Cocoa concepts, such as accessors and mutators.

Comment: @uttam: By the way, instead of writing `[self setCellIconNames:[NSArray ar...`, I could have used the new Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax `self.cellIconNames = [NSArray ar...`, but I prefer using the old bracket syntax.

Comment: @Steve, from last 3 hours i am goggling but its really worth to read ur answer...its working for me absolutely as what i need, thanks

Comment: @Pooja: Glad that you found it useful!